# How do i perform an operation on a child element and return the parent?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, flatmap

I have an array like this

```
const array = [
  { 
    name: 'Parent Brand 1', 
    childBrands: [
      { name: 'Child Brand 1', status: 'active' },
      { name: 'Child Brand 2', status: 'discontinued' },
    ] 
  }
, { 
    name: 'Parent Brand 2',
    childBrands: [
      { name: 'Child Brand 1', status: 'discontinued' },
      { name: 'Child Brand 2', status: 'active' },
    ] 
  }
];
```

How do I make it so that it filters the child brands by status and returns the parent object? After filtering by 'active' status it should return something like this,

```
const array = [
  { 
    name: 'Parent Brand 1', 
    childBrands: [
      { name: 'Child Brand 1', status: 'active' },
    ] 
  }
, { 
    name: 'Parent Brand 2',
    childBrands: [
      { name: 'Child Brand 2', status: 'active' },
    ] 
  }
];
```

Using a `flatMap` and `filter` only returns the child elements when i need the parent object including the child element

```
{ "name": "Child Brand 1","status": "active" }

{ "name": "Child Brand 2","status": "active" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't posted any code it's hard to know how you would be using `flatMap()` in this case. You can simply `map()` over the array and filter each nested array property.

```js
const array = [{ name: 'Parent Brand 1', childBrands: [{ name: 'Child Brand 1', status: 'active' }, { name: 'Child Brand 2', status: 'discontinued' },] }, { name: 'Parent Brand 2', childBrands: [{ name: 'Child Brand 1', status: 'discontinued' }, { name: 'Child Brand 2', status: 'active' },] }];

const filtered = array.map(parent => ({
  ...parent,
  childBrands: parent.childBrands.filter(child => child.status === 'active')
}));

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `Array#map` on the major array and `Array#filter` on the minor arrays as follows:

```js
const array = [ { name: 'Parent Brand 1', childBrands: [ { name: 'Child Brand 1', status: 'active' }, { name: 'Child Brand 2', status: 'discontinued' }, ] } , { name: 'Parent Brand 2', childBrands: [ { name: 'Child Brand 1', status: 'discontinued' }, { name: 'Child Brand 2', status: 'active' }, ] } ],

      output = array.map(
          ({childBrands,...rest}) =>
          ({
              ...rest,
              childBrands:childBrands.filter(
                  ({status}) => status === 'active'
              )
          })
      );
      
console.log( output );
```